# Why i need to use Navicat for a database of mysql using node.js ??

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, navicat

Am able to connect to database in node.js but i wonder where to create, store  and retrieve  my tables .

Comment: Well, you don't NEED to use Navicat... plenty of other GUI management tools out there.  Or just use the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sequelize js ORM,

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/schema/

This module can be used for defining the tables,

By the way no need to navicat for this, in case you have specific requirement please brief here.

Comment: Thanks for the info but actually my doubt is when i keep this total code in github people can able to see the data as am writing in js files i guess you got my point ??

Comment: If you are concern about the code protection, go for private repo in github. Other wise i don't get your point ?

Comment: If you find the answer satisfy. Accept and close. :)